# pause a function, usual suspects not seeming to work

Tags: jquery, delay, settimeout, colorbox

I've got a form in a colorbox. When it closes, another colorbox with a thank you message pops, then the window continues on to the destination page. I only want the delay if it comes from a successful submission. I've got that working, but no delay.

```
$form.validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
        $(document).bind('cbox_closed', function() {
            $.colorbox({href: 'thank_you.html'});
        });$.colorbox.close();
    },
//JSON STUFF
});
```

I'm trying to delay the second colorbox close function 8 seconds.

I've tried

```
});$.delay(8000).colorbox.close();
```

and

```
setTimeout($.colorbox.close(),8000);
```

but neither seems to help.

Answer (score 3):

`setTimeout($.colorbox.close(),8000)` will call the `close()` right away because you are executing the `close()` method, instead you should pass a handler or function pointer as first argument to `setTimeout` method . Try this.

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    $.colorbox.close()
}, 8000);
```

Comment: What happens then is that for some reason, colorbox seems to break, and it loads an empty page.

Comment: If I use that setTimeout, for some reason, what I get instead of a colorbox, the whole browser reloads, but with an empty page. There' just nothing there. If I don't use it, it works as normal.